# Site visited through Wifi

Tags: wireless-networking

We have a desktop computer at home which is connect by cable to a Bigpond router for access to the internet. My family usually connect to it via wifi on their ipads and/or phones (iphone & samsung). Is there any way I can tell what sites have been visited through the wifi?

Comment: Depending on the purpose, the best solutions are HTTP proxy (transparent) or Parental Control (Even Windows' does that)

Comment: What sort of Bigpond Router ? Bigpond locks down their routers pretty badly so even if the router had any sort of parental features, they're probably gone.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to put a HTTP-proxy between the user devices and the internet connection to log their activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like WireShark network protocol analyzer to see what they are visiting. Also, you could set up a proxy server, which would allow you to impose some restrictions if needed.

What operating system is desktop computer running?